# Jetpack Compose Canary Android Studio launch failing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-jetpack-compose

I want to learn Jetpack compose, so I have downloaded Jetpack Compose Preview Canary build version

[image: Canary version] **Version** : ARCTIC FOX 2020.3.1

I am getting error when trying to launch studio64 file

[image: error]

I have tried to install `jdk15` also but it did not help. I am using `jdk14` now

Please help me resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version released solved this problem, and Android studio is launching properly

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

[image]

**Version** : Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Canary 10

Note : Please do not use Canary 9 version, as it has the launching problem